# In ggplot2 is there a way to retrieve the commands used to make a plot in R?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

If I create a plot with this command:

```
bp <- ggplot(PlantGrowth, aes(x=group, y=weight)) + geom_boxplot()
```

Is there a way to get those ggplot2 commands out of bp?  I'm using a package (`cummeRbund`) that uses ggplot2 to plots output so the commands that generate the plots are wrapped up in a single command which obscures how the plot was generated.  I want to modify the plot and would like to see how it was generated-

```
ic<-csCluster(myGenes,k=7)

icp7(csClusterPlot(ic))
```

Comment: Consider: is there a guaranteed one-to-one relationship between a `grob` and the code which generated it?

Comment: It seems easier to look at the source code of `csClusterPlot`.

Comment: If you are willing to play around with it a little bit, you might be able to get the information you need by calling `str(bp)` and / or `summary(bp)`.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft but the ggplot object isn't a grob (yet), it needs to go through `ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(bp))`

Comment: @baptiste my apologies for bad choice of words.  I was misled by the assignment to the object `bp` , which is of `class` "gg ggplot" ; that's what I meant to refer to (or its components).

Comment: The simple answer is "No." The ggplot object cannot be uniquely cast back to the commands that created it anymore than a `data.frame` can recreate the exact `read.table` command that created it. There is information in the object about it's structure that may give clues as to how it was assembled but things like the original data.frame name seem to be lost.